# A value of type 'Iterable<HospitalListModel>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<HospitalListModel>'

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I got a flutter error `A value of type 'Iterable<HospitalListModel>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<HospitalListModel>'.` This is my model:

```
List<HospitalListModel> hospitalListModelFromJson(String str) => List<HospitalListModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => HospitalListModel.fromJson(x)));

String hospitalListModelToJson(List<HospitalListModel> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class HospitalListModel {
  HospitalListModel({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.content,
    this.image,
    this.phone,
    this.coordinates,
    this.website,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
  });

  dynamic id;
  dynamic title;
  dynamic content;
  dynamic image;
  dynamic phone;
  dynamic coordinates;
  dynamic website;
  dynamic createdAt;
  dynamic updatedAt;

  factory HospitalListModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => HospitalListModel(
    id: json["id"],
    title: json["title"],
    content: json["content"],
    image: json["image"],
    phone: json["phone"],
    coordinates: json["coordinates"],
    website: json["website"],
    createdAt: json["created_at"],
    updatedAt: json["updated_at"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "title": title,
    "content": content,
    "image": image,
    "phone": phone,
    "coordinates": coordinates,
    "website": website,
    "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
    "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
  };
}
```

and this is where the error come from, it's from the API provider and im confused why it throw iterable

```
class ApiProvider {
  final Dio _dio = Dio();
  final String _url = 'http://lovemonster.my.id/hospital';

  Future<List<HospitalListModel>> fetchHospitalList() async {
    try {
      List<HospitalListModel> hospitalList = [];
      Response response = await _dio.get(_url);
      var mData = response.data as List;
      hospitalList =  mData.
        map<HospitalListModel>((e) => hospitalListModelFromJson(e)
        .toList();
    return hospitalList;//return List not object
    } catch (error, stacktrace) {
    print("Exception occurred: $error stackTrace: $stacktrace");
    return Future.error("");
    }
  }
}
```

`hospitalList =  mData.map<HospitalListModel>((e) =>hospitalListModelFromJson(e).toList();`this code throw an error, and if you wondering how the other class or method, i will put event & state that seems related to the error:

state:

```
abstract class HospitalListState extends Equatable {
  const HospitalListState();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class HospitalListInitial extends HospitalListState {}

class HospitalListLoading extends HospitalListState {}

class HospitalListLoaded extends HospitalListState {
  final List<HospitalListModel> hospitalListModel;
  const HospitalListLoaded(this.hospitalListModel);
}

class HospitalListError extends HospitalListState {
  final String? message;
  const HospitalListError(this.message);
}
```

event:

```
abstract class HospitalListEvent extends Equatable {
  const HospitalListEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class GetCovidList extends HospitalListEvent {}
```

i made this code with `flutter_bloc` and if you want to know more details just let me know, and if you know what's wrong with my code, just type it on the answer, i appreciate every answers and knowledge that you share with me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A value of type 'Iterable<Food>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Food>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70404676/a-value-of-type-iterablefood-cant-be-assigned-to-a-variable-of-type-listf)

Comment: unfortunately not, but the problem is already solved, it just a silly mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed ')' before using toList method you have close the map method.

```
hospitalList =  mData.map<HospitalListModel>((e) => hospitalListModelFromJson(e))
   .toList();
```

Comment: hello, your answer is correct but would you help me with this error type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: You are trying to assign map type value to String type, so Dart is saying this error

Comment: im already edited my model just like above, but i know got another error, The return type 'List<HospitalListModel>' isn't a 'HospitalListModel', as required by the closure's context., if you don't mind do you know how to solve it?

Comment: that error was on hospitalList =  mData.map<HospitalListModel>((e) =>hospitalListModelFromJson(e)).toList();

Comment: Check the type of onhospitalList,

Comment: The error is saying you are trying to assign List of HospitalListModel into HospitalListModel value. change the type of of hospitalList

Comment: I think i can't change it because i want it in the form of list